# dataweave - Which is the best way to group orders and has the next result Mule 4

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4, mule-esb

I have the following scenario and problem, I try to group by "orderID" and remove the duplicate fields, but when I do it, I don't have the correct result because the group put all the elements in the same array and not as arrays of elements, I will show you:

In:

```
[
 {
  "orderId":"1110",
  "alternateNumber":"#CC16215",
  "shippingDate":"2022-04-26",
  "sku":"AC27",
  "unit":"1",
  "salePrice":"19.99"
},
{
  "orderId":"1110",
  "alternateNumber":"#CC16215",
  "shippingDate":"2022-04-26",
  "sku":"AC73",
  "unit":"1",
  "salePrice":"19.99"
},
{
  "orderId":"1112",
  "alternateNumber":"#CC16215",
  "shippingDate":"2022-04-12",
  "sku":"OBN03",
  "unit":"1",
  "salePrice":"19.99"
},
{
  "orderId":"1112",
  "alternateNumber":"#CC16215",
  "shippingDate":"2022-04-26",
  "sku":"OB04",
  "unit":"1",
  "salePrice":"19.99"
 }
]
```

Output obtained:

```
{
 "orderId": "1110",
 "alternateNumber": "#CC16215",
 "shippingDate": "2022-04-26",
 "products": [
 {
  "sku": "AC27",
  "salePrice": "19.99",
  "unit": "1"
 },
 {
  "sku": "AC73",
  "salePrice": "19.99",
  "unit": "1"
 }
],
"orderId": "1112",
"alternateNumber": "#CC16215",
"shippingDate": "2022-04-12",
"products": [
 {
  "sku": "OBN03",
  "salePrice": "19.99",
  "unit": "1"
 },
 {
  "sku": "OB04",
  "salePrice": "19.99",
  "unit": "1"
 }
 ]
}
```

Output expected:

```
[
 {
  "orderId":"1110",
  "alternateNumber":"#CC16215",
  "shippingDate":"2022-04-26",
  "products":[
     {
        "sku":"AC27",
        "salePrice":"19.99",
        "unit":"1"
     },
     {
        "sku":"AC73",
        "salePrice":"19.99",
        "unit":"1"
     }
    ]
  },
  {
  "orderId":"1112",
  "alternateNumber":"#CC16215",
  "shippingDate":"2022-04-12",
  "products":[
     {
        "sku":"OBN03",
        "salePrice":"19.99",
        "unit":"1"
     },
     {
        "sku":"OB04",
        "salePrice":"19.99",
        "unit":"1"
     }
    ]
   }
 ]
```

note: if you note the principal difference is the elements are separed by individual group of params.

My Code:

```
 payload groupBy ( $.orderId ) mapObject () -> {
  "orderId": $[0].orderId,
  "alternateNumber": $[0].alternateNumber,
  "shippingDate": $[0].shippingDate,
  "products": $ map {
    "sku": $.sku,
    "salePrice": $.salePrice,
    "unit": $.unit
   }
 }
```

As can be seen in the output obtained, it is putting all the elements as one and it does not separate them as in the expected output, which has elements separated by orderId and they are inside an array of arrays. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this script:

```
payload groupBy ( $.orderId ) pluck $  map (() -> {
  "orderId": $[0].orderId,
  "alternateNumber": $[0].alternateNumber,
  "shippingDate": $[0].shippingDate,
  "products": $ map {
    "sku": $.sku,
    "salePrice": $.salePrice,
    "unit": $.unit
}
})
```

Comment: Please select it as the answer to your ask and do so for all your other questions as well, as it helps folks who would be looking to solve a similar problem at some point in time.